# .NET Installer Project - Create shortcut keeps reinstalling everytime

Tags: .net, windows-installer

I have a .NET project (VS2008 .NET 3.5) that builds an exe.  I have an installer project as part of the same solution that creates an installer for that exe.

In the File System for the installer, I create a folder for my application under the User's Programs Menu.  In that new folder, I dump the .exe and .exe.config.  I also create a shortcut in that same folder AND a shortcut on the desktop.  The shortcut was created by right clicking on the "Primary output from Application(Active)" and selecting "Create shortcut to Primary output from Application(Active)".

Everything installs fine.  If I click on the .exe it runs fine.  When I click on either of the shortcuts though, it pops up this small "Installing" pop up window with a progress bar.  I have no idea where it came from or what it is doing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the pop-up window go away?  Does it pop-up each time the application is run, or only after a new installation?

Comment: Every single time I click on the shortcut it shows the installer pop up.  It doesn't seem like it's installing anything, as it goes way to fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason the product keeps re-installing as that the second shortcut (that keeps re-installing) is an "Advertised ShortCut" . If you touch anything in the application's target deployment directory then next time you run the application it will try to re-install to fix the issue.

See my post for a more detailed discussion:
[http://ntsblog.homedev.com.au/index.php/2011/08/17/setup-app-config-during-msi-install-msi-re-installing/](http://jcrawfor74.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/setup-app-config-during-msi-install-msi-re-installing/)

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the Windows Event Viewer (eventvwr.exe) and go to the "Application Log" you should see an event attributed to "Windows Installer". This will offer you what it is that is causing the repair activity. It will identify the component by its GUID so it won't seem helpful right away.

Open the installer in a tool like ORCA or [InstEd](http://www.instedit.com/) which are MSI editors to search the components table for the GUID identified in the error log.

At this point you at least know "what". I'd say that "why" will be an answer with a lot of variables difficult to pin down without using this process to better understand the problem with which you are dealing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot... but maybe check short cut's "Start In" property. Hopefully it's set to be where the Primary Output is installed.

I've seen other deployment installations behave oddly when the Start-In property is wrong.

Comment: Nope.  That was one of the first things I checked.  The "Start in" property is right.  The one weird thing about the shortcut is that the "Target" property is protected.  Also instead of being a full path to the .exe, it's just the name of the application that is somehow resolved then the shortcut is used.

Also what is funny is that if I make a new project and create an installer, I don't see the same problem.  Must be something funky about this specific project.

Comment: I saw the same behavior putting a test .exe into the "start menu/testfolder". It comes up with the install but _does_ start the program. Perhaps creating a folder (and installing the Primary Output there) in "Application Folder" instead of the "User's Programs Menu" and doing a short-cut from that location.

Comment: That's where I'm kind of hosed.  The users I'm developing for aren't privileged enough to install into the Application Folder.  So I have to install into the User's Programs Menu

Comment: Hmm... Perhaps you could install to one of the user's "special" folders. You can right click the root "File System on Target's Machine" and get a list of them. I would try finding My Documents folder or use Application data or Personal data folder.

Answer (score -2):

I think that I figured it out... and it leans towards me not understanding what the hell I was doing.  Originally, I would right click on the "Primary output from {project} (Active) item and select "Create shortcut to..." and that would create the shortcut that would in turn fire off the installer.

What I did different this time is right clicking on the file pane under the "User's Programs Menu" and selecting "Create Shortcut to {project}".  In the pop up window, navigate down to the "User's Programs Menu" and select the "Primary output from {project} (Active)" item and it will create a shortcut that works just fine when installed.

The only difference I can see once the app is installed, is that the Target of the one that works is pointing right at the project's exe.  The one that doesn't work lists the name of the application as the Target.

Two different ways of creating a shortcut to the exact same item in the Installer project.  There must be a fundamental difference that I'm not understanding.  For now I know how to make it work.

Thank you all for you input!

Comment: Both methods for creating the shortcut create the same output. The installer popping up is caused by the shorcut being an "Advertised Shortcut". The answer by jcrawford74 put me on the right path.